# Histogram output in Google Earth Engine

Tags: histogram, google-earth-engine

I am just running the sample code for generating histogram as shown in [Histograms](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/charts_image_histogram), and I see the bin count values are floating point. I can not understand it as it should be integer. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it out, it displays exactly as shown in the guide...

Maybe you got confused because of the minimized display:[image]

It becomes clearer when you use the full display:[image]

If so, *3,000* stands for 3000. It's not a floating point. ;)

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! Depending on which country you come from, it can be misleading at first. Btw: Don't forget to set the Answer (Checkmark below the voting element).